# PhoneListener in Service class in android

Tags: android, service

I am developing an android application in which I am using Service class for the Phone listener.

I need to get back the user to my application,after the call ends.

It works perfectly fine, but when my app is not closed and I try to call from the Android phone's Default dialler,at the end of the call it comes back to my application(which is not required).

How can I solve this?

Here is the Service class which I am using.

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
        {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
            {
            } 
            else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)
            {
                if(end.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"))
                {
                    Log.e("Service","end of cal - CAL IDLE ");
                    Intent i = new Intent(ServiceforPhone.this, PhoneCall.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);
                    end = "NO";
                    StopServ();
                }
            } 
            else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)
            {
                end = "YES";
                Log.e("Service"," of HOOK ");
            }
        }
    };

    TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if(mgr != null)
    {
        mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I think you need more complex logic in this case. Try to analize current activities on call end - if they contains your activity, than you should skip return, otherwhise - return to you app as now.

Here's example of code, which finds your activity in running:

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
        {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
            {
            } 
            else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)
            {
                if(end.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"))
                {
                    Log.e("Service","end of cal - CAL IDLE ");

                    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(100);
                    for (RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo : tasks) {
                        String packageName = runningTaskInfo.topActivity.getPackageName();
                        if packageName.equals(YOUR_ACTIVITY_PACKAGE)
                            // found our activity, exit
                            return;
                    }

                    // activity not founded, start
                    Intent i = new Intent(ServiceforPhone.this, PhoneCall.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);
                    end = "NO";
                    StopServ();
                }
            } 
            else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)
            {
                end = "YES";
                Log.e("Service"," of HOOK ");
            }
        }
    };
```

Also please note that this code needs permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```